# Isomorphism between finite structures which is not elementary

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

in the book by Katrin Tent and Martin Ziegler, "A course in model theory", it says that a complete theory in a finite relational language has quantifier eliminiation iff any isomorphism between finite substructures is elementary (Lemma 4.4.6.). I find this confusing since I thought that any isomorphism between two structures must be elementary, i. e. preserve the validity of all formulas. Can someone please find an error in my thought process and explain this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the book but I think it must be that a partial isomorphism $\mathfrak{A}\to \mathfrak{A}$ need not be elementary, as it is partial. This means that the quantifier-free type of the domain will be the same as that of the image, but the types (over $\mathfrak{A}$) need not be the same. A partial isomorphism is elementary when the types match too.

Comment: Elementary when formulas are interpreted in the big structures, not in the finite substructures.